# WWW::Mechanize Login on Twitch.tv using Perl

Tags: perl, authentication

I want to login on http://Twitch.tv, using PERL WWW::Mechanize.
Here is my Code (unfortunately it doesn't work). It would be great if it can be fixed :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;

$username = 'secret';           
$pwd = 'secretAlso';
$url = "https://secure.twitch.tv/login";

$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get($url);

$mech->form_name('login-form');
$mech->field(login => $username);
$mech->field(password => $pwd);
$mech->submit();
print $mech->status();
```

> 200

Code 200 says "OK", but if i print the content...

```
print $mech->content();
```

I get only Source code from Login page. What is wrong?

Comment: Thank you for response. print $mech->status(); 200

Comment: HTTP 200 means the request was successful.

Comment: Code 200 says "OK", but if i print the content...

    print $mech->content();  

... i get only Sourcecode from Loginpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at at the form in question. It does not have a an id or a name.

```
<form class="js-login-form login_form " method="post" action="https://secure-login.twitch.tv/login" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Mechanize does have a  [form_with_fields()](http://%3Cform%20class=%22js-login-form%20login_form%20%22%20method=%22post%22%20action=%22https://secure-login.twitch.tv/login%22%20accept-charset=%22UTF-8%22%3E%20%3Cdiv%20style=%22margin:0;padding:0;display:inline%22%3E%20%3Cinput%20type=%22hidden%22%20value=%22%E2%9C%93%22%20name=%22utf8%22%3E%20%3Cinput%20type=%22hidden%22%20value=%22VlLcV6IrskCyKPTFmMZnkLa0JswghakiDqOvMOeQAgk=%22%20name=%22authenticity_token%22%3E%20%3C/div%3E%20%3Cinput%20id=%22redirect_on_login%22%20type=%22hidden%22%20value=%22https://secure.twitch.tv/%22%20name=%22redirect_on_login%22%3E%20%3Cinput%20id=%22embed_form%22%20type=%22hidden%22%20value=%22false%22%20name=%22embed_form%22%3E%20%3Cinput%20id=%22mp_source_action%22%20type=%22hidden%22%20value=%22%22%20name=%22mp_source_action%22%3E%20%3Cinput%20id=%22follow%22%20type=%22hidden%22%20value=%22%22%20name=%22follow%22%3E%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22field%20item%22%3E%20%3Clabel%20class=%22label%22%3EUsername%3C/label%3E%20%3Cinput%20id=%22login_user_login%22%20class=%22field%20text%20med-long%22%20type=%22text%22%20name=%22login%22%20autofocus=%22autofocus%22%3E%20%3C/div%3E%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22field%20item%22%3E%20%3Clabel%20class=%22label%22%3EPassword%3C/label%3E%20%3Cinput%20id=%22password%22%20class=%22field%20text%20med-long%22%20type=%22password%22%20value=%22%22%20name=%22password%22%3E%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22help%20sub%22%3E%20%3C/div%3E%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22buttons%22%3E%20%3Cbutton%20class=%22button%20primary%22%20type=%22submit%22%20tabindex=%2211%22%3ELog%20In%20%3C/button%3E%20%3C/div%3E%20%3Cimg%20class=%22js-loading-spinner%20spinner%22%20style=%22display:none%22%20src=%22/images/spinner.gif%22%3E%20%3C/form%3E) method that allows selecting a form based on the fields it contains.

Comment: Thank you Josh! Do you know a way to get access with perl?